# Chrome Custom Tabs: Icon state and responding to user actions

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

It looks like the custom tab icon is static, so it couldn't respond to user changes or external changes?

To take the Pinterest example, if Pinterest has a custom tab icon like "Pin It" and user clicks on it, can it be changed to "Pinned". If not, how should the app/tab provide user feedback after such an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon can not be changed at the moment. Not sure how to handle that though.

Comment: I believe a toast can be shown, so that's probably the best we can do at present.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now [implemented in Chrome 46] (https://codereview.chromium.org/1291083004/) together with the next version of android support library that will be released soon.

There are two ways to update the icon of action button:

1. Using support library, you could call CustomTabSession#setActionButton(), once you have got an CustomTabSession object after creating a custom tab.
2. If you prefer not to use the easy and beautiful support library, you could also achieve the same goal by binding to the [CustomTabsService](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/android/support/customtabs/ICustomTabsService.aidl&q=CustomTabsService&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=14), call updateVisuals() and pass the IBinder object you got previously when binding.

Comment: Interesting workaround but reloading the page is also reloading the page state and that could cause some major ux problems.